# why my document.write is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, document.write

Here is my document.write function which is not working. Please tell me and help in resolving the issues. I want to place this "document.write" in one single .js file and include that in all my html pages. But at first "document.write" is not working. :( thanks

```
document.write("
<table><td><img src=allpages.png style=width: 80%;></img><br>
<select name='Archive' value='Archive'style=' background-color: black;
padding: 3px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px; border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px ‪#‎CCC‬, 0px -1px ‪#‎FFF‬ inset;
color: yellow; border: medium none;
outline: medium none; text-align: right;
display: inline-block; width: 80%;
cursor: pointer; '>
<option onclick=javascript:location.href=index.html><a href='#'>صفحہ اول</a></option>
<option onclick=javascript:location.href=2.html><a href='2.html'>دوسرا صفحہ</a></option>
<option onclick=javascript:location.href=3.html>تیسرا صفحہ</option>
<option onclick=javascript:location.href=4.html>چوتھا صفحہ</option>
</select></td>

<td><img src=allnewspapers.png style= 'width: 80%;'></img><br>
<select name=Archive value=Archive
style='background-color: black;
padding: 3px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #CCC, 0px -1px #FFF inset;
color: yellow; border: medium none;
outline: medium none; text-align: right;
display: inline-block; width: 80%;
cursor: pointer;'>
<option>جنوری 2015</option>
<option>فروری 2015</option>
</select></td></table>");
```

Comment: you will need to put the html right first, you're not qouting where you should, for instance , line 1 `img src=allpages.png` needs to be `img src='allpages.png'`

Comment: @Billy - no it doesn't. `src=allpages.png` is fine - you don't need quotes there. But `style=width: 80%;` needs to be `style='width: 80%;'` because otherwise the space will terminate the attribute value too early.

Comment: @Alohci, you're correct. I did actually know that without spaces or certain chars was ok, I just grabbed the first attr I saw, my bad.

Comment: i did the same. yet it says "Error: Expected: ;"

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is the best way of doing that. However, your code works when used without the line breaks at the end of each line.

```
document.write("<table><td><img src=allpages.png style=width: 80%;></img><br><select name='Archive' value='Archive'style=' background-color: black;padding: 3px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px; border-radius: 10px;box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px ‪#‎CCC‬, 0px -1px ‪#‎FFF‬ inset;color: yellow; border: medium none;outline: medium none; text-align: right;display: inline-block; width: 80%;cursor: pointer; '><option onclick=javascript:location.href=index.html><a href='#'>صفحہ اول</a></option><option onclick=javascript:location.href=2.html><a href='2.html'>دوسرا صفحہ</a></option><option onclick=javascript:location.href=3.html>تیسرا صفحہ</option><option onclick=javascript:location.href=4.html>چوتھا صفحہ</option></select></td><td><img src=allnewspapers.png style= 'width: 80%;'></img><br><select name=Archive value=Archivestyle='background-color: black;padding: 3px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 10px;box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #CCC, 0px -1px #FFF inset;color: yellow; border: medium none;outline: medium none; text-align: right;display: inline-block; width: 80%;cursor: pointer;'><option>جنوری 2015</option><option>فروری 2015</option></select></td></table>");
```

Comment: sir it is still not working

Comment: Enclosed within a `<script>` tag, this works..

Comment: I wrote this in .js file. It gives error when I launch it. Error: "Expected: ;"

Comment: Is this the only line you have in the .js file? This could an error on another line. Check the line number of the error in browser's console.

Comment: it says line 3 character 32. Expected: ;

Comment: can you show us the complete code? what is there in line 3? Did you not use the command in a single line?

Comment: the comment box is limited. I cant paste the code.

Comment: I think you can still edit the question to add it. Anyway, you may recreate the error on jsfiddle.net..

Answer (score 0):

Avoid pressing enter while typing inside *write* function. It works!!!

```
document.write("<table><td><img src='allpages.png' style='width: 80%;'></img><br>    <select name='Archive' value='Archive'style=' background-color: black; padding: 3px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px; border-radius: 10px;    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #ccc,0px -1px ‪#‎FFF‬ inset;    color: yellow; border: medium none;    outline: medium none; text-align: right;    display: inline-block; width: 80%;    cursor: pointer;'>    <option onclick=javascript:location.href=index.html><a href='#'>صفحہ اول</a></option>  <option onclick=javascript:location.href=2.html><a href='2.html'>دوسرا صفحہ</a></option>    <option onclick=javascript:location.href=3.html>تیسرا صفحہ</option>    <option onclick=javascript:location.href=4.html>چوتھا صفحہ</option></select></td> <td><img src='allnewspapers.png' style= 'width: 80%;'></img><br>    <select name=Archive value=Archive    style='background-color: black;   padding: 3px; margin: 0px; margin-top: 5px;    -moz-border-radius: 4px;    border-radius: 10px;    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #CCC, 0px -1px #FFF inset;    color: yellow; border: medium none;    outline: medium none; text-align: right;    display: inline-block; width: 80%;    cursor: pointer;'>   <option>جنوری 2015</option>   <option>فروری 2015</option>  </select></td></table>");
```

Comment: It works, but do you really want to have that? Let's say you want to edit one of the options...

Answer (score 0):

The problem itself is caused by the fact that strings are only allowed to be on single lines. So this is invalid:

```
var syntaxErrorString = "test
test";
```

There are three ways around this:

1. Concatenation:

   ```
   var concatenatedString = "test\n" +
   "test";
   ```
2. Escaping:

   ```
   var escapedString = "test\n\
   test";
   ```
3. Condensing:

   ```
   var condensedString = "test\ntest";
   ```

I'd suggest going with "none of the above". It is far easier to have some server-side language such as PHP, define your block of HTML as, say, `navigation.html`, and then just write `<?php include "navigation.html"; ?>` when you want it. Much better.